# How can I set identity_insert on a tablename passed as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have the Database name in a `@strDBName`. I build the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` and execute it. There's no error, but a subsequent insert fails. The code below illustrates the problem.

```
  Declare @Query Varchar(MAX)
  SET @Query = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+ @strDBName +'..TableName ON'
  EXEC(@Query)


  INSERT INTO [TableName] ... (MAX) Value from another table and other applicable record.


  SET @Query = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+ @strDBName +'..TableName OFF'
  EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: I believe dynamic sql is executed in a separate session. You can make this all happen as one dynamic sql statement though and it should work. If you di that you'll have to use output parameters and and `sp_executesql` to get the Max value back.

Comment: Thanks Brad !
I have try these

Comment: Be careful if this is going into production.  This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I see you are inserting by pulling MAX from another table. This has a code smell to it that sounds like you are going to be wrestling with concurrency issues in the future. Not to mention that it seems like a bad idea to use identity if you are just going to insert values from another table anyway. Why not just make the column an int?

Comment: The insert statement should a dynamic sql as well. It doesn't have the database suffix.

Comment: When you find yourself parameterising tables (i.e. you have multiple tables with the same columns) it's often a sign that the model is broken and what you should have is a single table with additional column(s) storing the *data* that's currently being "stored" in those table names. That is, you shouldn't normally have `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to backup Brad's answer given in the comments, here's an MVCE of doing the entire insertion sequence in a single dynamic query. As per Kris' comment, ensure that the database name is white listed, as the query is vulnerable to SqlInjection (unfortunately, database names cannot be parameterized in dynamic sql via `sp_executesql`)

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
);
```

A single batch can be executed:

```
DECLARE @strDBName VARCHAR(100) = 'MyDatabase';
Declare @Query Varchar(MAX)
SET @Query = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+ @strDBName +'..TableName ON; '
SET @Query = @Query + 'INSERT INTO '+ @strDBName 
 +'..[TableName](ID) SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID), 0)+1 FROM '+ @strDBName +'..TableName; '
SET @Query = @Query + 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+ @strDBName +'..TableName OFF;'
EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: Maybe even wrap the whole thing in `if exists(select * from sys.databases where name = @strDBName) begin ... end` to protect against bad dbnames/sql injection

Comment: Every time we call EXECUTE it runs the command as a separate batch with its own context, so we need to put everything in the @Query  and EXECUTE just once. 
Thanks  StuartLC !