# Execute dynamic SQL from Entity Framework Core without a warning

Tags: c#, dynamic-sql, string-interpolation, ef-core-2.2

I'm with a task of enable/disable `IDENTITY_INSERT` for some tables in SQL Server. I can do it using like `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetTable ON`. Please note the table name cannot be passed as parameter. The next code snippet **WILL NOT WORK**:

```sql
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)
SET @tableName = 'TargetTable'
SET IDENTITY_INSERT @tableName ON;
```

No problem for me, I will do it via C# and Entity Framework Core, like this:

```cs
string sqlCmd = $@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {name} ON;";
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sqlCmd);
```

But this code yields a warning:

> Warning
>   The SQL expression passed to 'ExecuteSqlCommandAsync' embeds data that will not be parameterized. Review for potential SQL injection vulnerability. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=871170 for more information.

But how I explained previously, the table name cannot be passed as parameter.

What can I do to satisfy this warning message? I really want to avoid it, but I think I will need use pragmas like this:

```
#pragma warning disable EF1000
```

Comment: Does [this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833373/3034273)?

Comment: @Xerillio Yes and No. "Yes" because we can pass the tablename as parameter, and then no warning will appear. But "No" because it will not answer the problem: we cannot build any type of dynamic sql concatenating or interpolating string, because not every thing we need concatenate will be truly a "data parameter".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you need to insert some data using EF and then turn IDENTITY_INSERT ON and OFF before and after? Can you show what it is you need this for with some code? That would make it easier to understand

Comment: I can't reproduce this using EF 2.2.6.